# Receive data via MPC in a TableView - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multipeer-connectivity, mpc

I'm facing difficulty sending data via MPC, communication is working correctly between the devices is being printed on a TextView my need is to be presented in a table view, I can add and remove objects from a table view via MPC, does anyone know if it is possible or if it's just the impression the MPC is in TextView.

Thank you.

I thank you.

I will let down my code that sends and receives.

Send data

```
-(void) inputIDTransporte {

//testando IDController
IDController * idC = [[IDController alloc] init];


[idC loadIdInput:_textView.text];

//mudando mensagem de saida
[idC.idValues replaceObjectAtIndex:9 withObject:_textField.text];

[idC generateIDOutputByComponentsScheme];

NSLog(@"idValues:%@", idC.idValues);
NSLog(@"idOutput:%@", idC.idOutput);

NSLog(@"index9: %@",idC.idValues[9]);

NSString* str= [idC.idValues objectAtIndex:9];
NSData* dataToSend=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *allPeers = _appDelegate.mcManager.session.connectedPeers;
NSError *error;

[_appDelegate.mcManager.session sendData:dataToSend
                                 toPeers:allPeers
                                withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable
                                   error:&error];
[idC.componentsScheme setValue:str forKey:@"name"];
[self.tableView reloadData];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

}

Receive data

-(void)didReceiveDataWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{

```
MCPeerID *peerID = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"peerID"];
NSString *peerDisplayName = peerID.displayName;

NSData *receivedData = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
NSString *receivedText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[_tvChat performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[_tvChat.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", receivedText]] waitUntilDone:NO];
[_tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Multipeer connectivity merely provides a way for devices to communicate - it places no restrictions on how communicated information is presented.

You can certainly display received data in a table. If you look at [CoachKit](https://github.com/NativeMobile/CoachKit) you will see there is an example app that does exactly that - it displays messages received from another device in a table.